# Getting TH value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get header text in array, however with following I am getting value plus th tag i.e `[<th>value1</th>, <th>value2</th>]`, I want to get `[value1, value2]`.

```
$('#header').children().each(function(){this.html});
```

Here is how my HTML looks like:

```
<tr bgcolor="#cdb79e" id="header">
    <th>Origin Code</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Engine</th>
    <th>Network</th>
    <th>Platform</th>
    <th>Expansion Tool</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Imps</th>
    <th>Clicks</th>
    <th>Engine CTR</th>
    <th>Average Position</th>
    <th>Picks</th>
    <th>LP CTR</th>
    <th>GSL Picks</th>
    <th>GSL LP CTR</th>
    <th>Merchant Picks</th>
    <th>Merchant LP CTR</th>
    <th>CPC</th>
    <th>RPC</th>
    <th>RPP</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Total Rev</th>
    <th>Margin</th>
    <th>ROI</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: You could strip the tags using regex, but that would not be very pretty. Feels like there should be a better alternative.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: You could use `$(this).html()` - see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qof6ustx/). The `html()` method uses the `innerHTML` property and should not return any outer tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your HTML were to look something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id='header'>
            <th>Value1</th>
            <th>Value2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

You could use something like this to build an array of the `<th>` elements' text:

```
var headerArray = [];
$('#header').children().each(function(){
    headerArray.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(headerArray);
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks

Comment: You can also use `map` instead of `each`, it has a cleaner syntax IMO. `$('#header').children().map(function(){return this.innerHTML;})`

Comment: [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is a bit more appropriate: `$('#header').children().map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get()`